# Link a .c file with a main.c file

Tags: c, linker

I wrote a function for a class and I need to submit it so it works when compiled.

main.c header looks like...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

my function code fun.c looks like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.c"
```

yet for some reason they're not linking together.  When I compile and run I don't get an error, it just runs main.c as if fun.c doesn't exist, meaning it ignores the function call to fun.c and runs the program without executing what I need to display.

I wrote the code together in main.c, so I know the function works.  I'm just having a little trouble splitting it up into two separate .c files and linking them.

thanks for any help

//edit & updates

compiling with gcc -m32 -O1 *.c    the two files in the directory are fun.c and main.c

Basically we're submitting a function that has to work with the main.c that is provided but we're not aloud to modify the main.c so i'm not sure how to add it to my function so they both compile/link together

Comment: You (generally) don't include `.c` files in other `.c` files. Also please post your makefile or compiler/linker command-line arguments to your question.

Comment: Try `gcc -Wall -m32 -O1 main.c fun.c -o exename` where `exename` is whatever you choose to call the executable.

Comment: Oh, and as Dai mentioned, remove the `#include "main.c"` from fun.c

Comment: "When I compile and run I don't get an error, it just runs main.c as if fun.c doesn't exist" - If the program is running, then there's no linkage error. The symbols (global functions and variables) in file func.c that your program refers to are successfully resolved into memory addresses, which means that you **do** have them as part of your executable image.

Comment: What does the function call in `main.c` that calls the `function` in `fun.c` look like? We can guess all night, but unless you post your code, we are going nowhere but further into the realm of speculation.

Comment: add a fun.h file and include that in main.c file. In fun.h file, give the prototype of the function declared in fun.c file.

Answer (score 0):

Please use other names for your outsource files in future, main.c is inconvenient. The right way to do it is: Create a header file for your outsource main.c. It should be named main.h. There you will declare your functions for instance: **addNumbers(int a, int b);** Then you open your outsource main.c file and there you **#include "main.h"**. Open then your fun.c file and **#include "main.h"**. After everything has been done right, compile your main file: **gcc -c -o fun.o fun.c** » Then your outsource file: **gcc -c -o main.o main.c** » Now link the two files together: **gcc -o name main.o fun.o** Then you are able to execute your program.